# SBT deploy image to ECR and then use the image in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ecr

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to associate an image from the elastic container registry with an elastic beanstalk environment. I'm modifying a project that used to upload the image to S3, and I'm changing it so that it stores the image in ECR instead.

The registry for the image and the EB environment are both currently being set up with terraform. Previously the S3 bucket for the image was set in the docker settings of my `build.sbt` file, but I cannot find an equivalent for stating the name of the ECR repository. I am able to successfully deploy my docker image to ECR using the `sbt-ecr` plugin, but I cannot find anything that would then let elastic beanstalk know where this image is.

This is my first time using EB so I might just be misunderstanding how it works, but I honestly can't see any link between the code and EB. The deployment pipeline previously just ran

`sbt realease with-defaults`

and then

`aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name <env-name> --version-label <version>`

How am I supposed to tell it to look for the image in the ECR repository? I don't even understand how it was working before, let alone how to get it to work now. All of the EB plugins I've found have just deployed the local image to EB rather than using something deployed somewhere. When I google the general issue I keep seeing things telling me to add stuff to my `Dockkerrun.aws.json` file, but I guess that's something that sbt has previously been building for me as I've never seen it before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.